# Interfaces with non-physical interfaces

Tags: 14.04, networking, ip, ifconfig

I found a rather big difference between some boxes I have (some are debian... some ubuntu), and I'm not sure why... or what the fix might be.

Essentially... if I create an "iface" entry in interfaces that doesn't actually exist with my own configuration to bring the interface up & down... ubuntu complains

```
user@blah:~# sudo ifup mgmt
Cannot find device "mgmt"
Failed to bring up mgmt.
```

the interface is defined in ubuntu as such:

```
iface mgmt inet manual
  up ip netns add mgmt
  up ip link set eth2 netns mgmt
  up ip netns exec mgmt ifconfig eth2 10.0.0.19/24 up
  down ip netns exec mgmt ifconfig eth2 down
  down ip netns exec mgmt ip link set eth2 netns 1
  down ip netns delete mgmt
```

If I do the same thing on debian... the interface comes up with no issues.  The odd thing is that if I don't have the mgmt interface defined... I get a completely different error:

```
Ignoring unknown interface mgmt=mgmt.
```

Running the same thing with the verbose flag... shows ubuntu is trying to bring the interface up before anything else is done.  No clue why.

Comment: It looks like somewhere ubuntu adds an extra `ip link set dev mgmt   up` despite it being absent from the interfaces file and ifquery.  Any ideas folks?

Comment: It looks like this issue is limited to Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: According to the official documentation `ifup` works with the Configuration Files found in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`. What have you placed there?

Comment: @BodoHugoBarwich Sadly, with 14.04 there is no /etc/sysconfig directory... but I did dig through the if-*.d scripts... and nothing relevant was found.

Comment: Hi @TheCompWiz Have you tried those steps documented at https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html ?

Comment: The document at https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html#ethernet-interfaces suggests to look at the file `/etc/network/interfaces` and to compare the configuration with the sample in the document

Comment: I've gone through every bit of documentation from Canonical... I've gone through every script in every related directory that I can find... and nothing does an `up` on the interface... yet... when running `ifup --verbose` the very first line still includes the `up` on the interface.  This does not occur with 12.04, or 16.04.  Just 14.04.

Comment: Can I understand your Objective as different **Configurations** that you want to switch against each other according the Network that your are in but on the same **Physical Interface** (for example Networking Card)? Or do you seek to create several **Virtual Interfaces** that run all together on the same Physical Interface at the same time. The Concept of different **Configurations** does only come with the new *NetworkManager*.

Comment: @BodoHugoBarwich I simply want to be able to define a set of rules that will bring up interfaces and apply configurations as needed.  In particular... for this particular setup, I will need to create a network namespace, and move an interface into the other namespace, and apply various relevant configurations.  You cannot say that "different configurations" only comes with the new NetworkManager... as this works with 12.04... as well as current releases of Ubuntu.  Only 14.04 is affected.